# Como Pegar o título e a foto de capa de um álbum compartilhado do Google Fotos

Tags: html, python

Como faço para pegar o título e a foto de capa de um álbum compartilhado do Google Fotos a partir do link de compartilhamento?

Se você publicar no Facebook o link de um álbum compartilhado do Google Fotos, vai ver que o Facebook apresenta a foto de capa e o título do álbum. Eu quero fazer exatamente isso, mas pelo que pesquisei não há uma API disponível para esse fim.

Comment: Você poderia postar um exemplo de um álbum público? Gostaria de utilizar a API do Google? Já possui algum código?

Comment: Essa [API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python) não serve para este fim?